# Call model function into custom middleware file in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel. I am developing an application from scratch as of now I just used laravel auth i.e (php artisan make:auth).

My requirement is to pull data for a loggedin user from a table i.e "admin" into my custom middleware but I am unable to call function which is defined in my Model i.e "Admin" file.

MODEL FILE :- app\Admin.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
     public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'admin_role', 'admin_id', 'role_id');
    }
    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function myfunction($val)
    {
        echo "===>".$val; exit ;
    }
}
```

MIDDLEWARE FILE :- app\Http\Middleware\CheckRole.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $request->admin->myfunction('customvalue');
        exit ; 
    }
}
```

I need to call  function i.e "myfunction" which is define in Admin model into Checkrole.php middleware.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
auth()->user()->myfunction();
```

from the middleware. ( I am assuming you have an authenticated user at this point)

Comment: Hi , thanks for the response but unfortunately it doesn't work . I am getting "Call to a member function myfunction() on a non-object" error and I have edited my question, can you please review again?

Comment: are you sure that you are authenticated as a user?  what does dd(auth()->check()); do in the middleware?

Comment: It returns "false"

Comment: that means the user is not logged in. I did mention that the function is only for authenticated users.

Comment: I am using auth for both admin and frontend , for admin part I have "admins" table and for frontend I have "users" table. And I am easily able to make separate login for both and are working fine. But don't know why I am getting "false" message after debugging.

Comment: I got the solution dd ( Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name )  works fine. Anyways thanks for the help.